# How the exclude directive works in the go.mod file?

Tags: go

The new Go version 1.11 introduced the modules concept which is awesome.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#gomod) it says there are four directives that can be used in a `go.mod` file: `module`, `require`, `exclude`, `replace`.

It also explains that:

> exclude and replace directives only operate on the current (“main”)
>   module. exclude and replace directives in modules other than the main
>   module are ignored when building the main module. The replace and
>   exclude statements therefore allow the main module complete control
>   over its own build, without also being subject to complete control by
>   dependencies.

But I still don't understand how the `exclude` directive works.

Can someone explain to me how the `exclude` directive works and if possible give an example of when to use it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a semi-hypothetical hypothetical example:

## go.mod

```
module github.com/example/project

require (
    github.com/SermoDigital/jose v0.0.0-20180104203859-803625baeddc
    github.com/google/uuid v1.1.0
)

exclude github.com/SermoDigital/jose v0.9.1

replace github.com/google/uuid v1.1.0 => git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/uuid.go v1.1.1
```

## exclude

In the case of the `github.com/SermoDigital/jose` package, it has a proper git tag for `v0.9.1`, but the current version is `v1.1`, which is **NOT** a proper git tag (missing the "patch" version).

By excluding the properly-versioned (but not working) code it causes go mod to fetch from `master` instead (which is not properly versioned, but has the working code).

## replace

Likewise (and truly hypothetical), if I have a patch to `github.com/google/uuid`, I can create a fork and use `replace` to get my own version while I wait for the upstream version to accept my patch (or not).

Comment: "By excluding the broken version". In the example `go.mod` file, you exclude `v0.9.1`. Per this statement, did you mean to exclude `v1.1`, or am I still misunderstanding the purpose of the `exclude` directive?

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage v0.9.1 is a PROPER semver git tag, but the code is broken. v1.1 has the WORKING code, but the git tag is not parsable as semver.